# Cannot access $node on Computed field

Tags: nodes, entities

I'm using computed field for my content types, but when I used $node, in Display Code, it doesn't display anything :

```
global $node;
$display_output = l("Apply", "apply_form?job_offer=".$node->nid);
```

Comment: What version of the module do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are supposed to write to `$entity_field[0]['value']`. Second problem is that fields operate on entities, not nodes, so you need to use `$entity` instead. You can always use Devel module and `dpr($entity)` to see what's in it.

`node id` should be in the entity field if it is a node. In which case you can load it with `node_load()`.

Comment: node id should be in the entity field if it is a node. In which case you can load it with `node_load();`

Comment: Thank you, some example here : https://drupal.org/node/149232

Comment: @Bibix glad you found it :) hope it works for you now.